# Wordpress Activating Plugin Not Creating DB Table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to create a DB Table on activation of my plugin. However, it is not being created and I have no clue why. The location of the file is correct and I have tried with both $wpdb->query and $dbDelta of which neither seem to work.

The following code is found in the includes/davi-referrals-install.php file.

```
<?php
/*
*Create database table on plugin activation
*/

function dr_activation () {
    global $wpdb;
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    //Table Used To Store Referrer Accounts
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "dr_accounts"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name text NOT NULL,
        email varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(64) NOT NULL
        companyname text NOT NULL,
        telephone text NOT NULL,
        code text NOT NULL,
        balance text NOT NULL,
        registered datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}?>
```

Main Plugin File:

```
//Return Plugin Installation Process
function referral_activation(){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'includes/davi-referrals-install.php';
    dr_activation();
} register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'referral_activation');
```

The error I am getting with WP_DEBUG enabled is, this no longer displays when I remove the dr_activation() function call:

The plugin generated 777 characters of unexpected output during activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling the following it was easy to find:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

I had missed a comma after the password declaration:

```
password varchar(64) NOT NULL
companyname text NOT NULL,
```

Solution:

```
    password varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    companyname text NOT NULL,
```